# Url Rewriting Issue in Yii

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I want to rewrite my yii application urls ,i just doen it and it works fine in my local machine . but when i move to server it is not working and shows a 500 Internal Server error

My current url is like this

cvdb.example.com/index.php/list/index

i want to rewrite it as

cvdb.example.com/list/index

Here is my code in config/main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                                'showScriptName'=>false,
                                'caseSensitive'=>false,
                                'rules'=>array(
                                        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                                ),
                        ),
```

And here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here what i get when i put var_dumb($_SERVER)

```
array(39) {
["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
string(29) "/home/bridge/public_html/cvdb"
["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
string(7) "CGI/1.1"
["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
string(63) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=>
string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.5"
["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
string(5) "close"
["HTTP_COOKIE"]=>
string(339) "fbm_1=base_domain=.cvdb.example.com; PHPSESSID=a6b697793d5abf01012435cf868a2f13; 52862fa7c29cebef614e5f38c01514c2=5571bdfdfdfdfdfdfb1ed61d4cae29f6145035a37a9d4ee45e83a%3A4%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A13%3A%22Administrator%22%3Bi%3A2%3Bi%3A31536000%3Bi%3A3%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A4%3A%22role%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2210%22%3B%7D%7D"
["HTTP_HOST"]=>
string(23) "cvdb.example.com"
["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
string(72) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]=>
string(14) "220.336.5.3"
["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"]=>
string(23) "cvdb.example.com"
["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER"]=>
string(23) "cvdb.example.com"
["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]=>
string(14) "220.336.5.3"
["PATH"]=>
string(13) "/bin:/usr/bin"
["PHPRC"]=>
string(13) "/home/bridge/"
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
string(0) ""
["REDIRECT_PHPRC"]=>
string(13) "/home/bridge/"
["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=>
string(3) "200"
["REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID"]=>
string(24) "UtTWkTIfkzwAAddfdFUWCbwAAAAD"
["REDIRECT_URL"]=>
string(11) "/list/index"
["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
string(14) "220.227.90.185"
["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
string(5) "43681"
["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
string(3) "GET"
["REQUEST_URI"]=>
string(11) "/list/index"
["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
string(39) "/home/bridge/public_html/cvdb/index.php"
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
string(10) "/index.php"
["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
string(12) "50.31.147.60"
["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
string(33) "webmaster@cvdb.example.com"
["SERVER_NAME"]=>
string(23) "cvdb.example.com"
["SERVER_PORT"]=>
string(2) "80"
["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
string(8) "HTTP/1.0"
["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
string(0) ""
["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
string(156) "Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2           mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.4.3 mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_perl/2.0.6 Perl/v5.8.8"
["UNIQUE_ID"]=>
string(24) "UtTWkTIfkzwAAFUWCbwAAAAD"
["ORIG_PATH_INFO"]=>
string(11) "/list/index"
["ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED"]=>
string(39) "/home/bridge/public_html/cvdb/index.php"
["PHP_SELF"]=>
string(10) "/index.php"
["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
int(1389680273)
["argv"]=>
array(0) {
}
["argc"]=>
int(0)
```

}

Comment: does your application run without rewriting urls in server?

Comment: Check your Apache error.log and see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on the engine:
RewriteEngine on
# Don't perform redirects for files and directories that exist:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# For everything else, redirect to index.php:
RewriteRule . index.php
</ifModule>
```

Or just try removing this line simply from your .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Hi i changed htaccess like this but still having the issue 500 internal server error.

Comment: Then the problem might be with the web access.check whether you have placed the project in the right directory and you are passing the right url

Comment: Yes it is working project as i can access the site with out this htaccess correctly.

Comment: then try changing the file with my updated code as it works fine for me

Comment: Hi just did this one also, getting an error like The page isn't redirecting properly. Actually the htaccess and config/main.php worked for me in my local machine and i done url rewriting there.

Comment: I tryed both methods but it doesn't work for me.. :(